# Static Suggestion. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, static

So I am trying to pass an ArrayList to my main method, but eclipse is telling me I need to change my arraylist to a static. I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

```
ArrayList<Patient> pList = Doctor.getPatientList();
```

this is the call I have in my main method.

```
public class Doctor {
public ArrayList<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();
}

public void loadPatientData() {
    BufferedReader read2 = null;

    try {   
        read2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/patient_list.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = read2.readLine()) != null) {
            line = read2.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            String[] lineValues = line.split(","); //split the string on this value into array
            String firstName = lineValues[0];
            String lastName = lineValues[1];
            String address = lineValues[2];
            String city = lineValues[3];
            String state = lineValues[4];
            String zip = lineValues[5];
            String ssn = lineValues[6];
            String genderNeedsConvert = lineValues[7];
            String weightNeedsDouble = lineValues[8];
            String heightNeedsDouble = lineValues[9];
            String symptomsNotReady = lineValues[10]; // these need to be broken up further (using semicolons)

            char gender = genderNeedsConvert.charAt(0);
            double weight = Double.parseDouble(weightNeedsDouble);
            double height = Double.parseDouble(heightNeedsDouble);

            Patient patient = new Patient(firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zip, ssn, gender, weight, height, symptomsNotReady); 
            patientList.add(patient); // must be of patient type.
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (read2 != null) {
            try {
                read2.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      }
    }
public ArrayList<Patient> getPatientList() {
    return patientList;
}
```

This is a shortened version of my Doctor class.

```
public class Patient {

private String patientID;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String ssn;
private char gender;
private String address;
private String city;
private String state;
private String symptoms;
private String zip;
public ArrayList<Diagnosis> diagnoses = new ArrayList<Diagnosis>();
//private Diagnosis diagnoses = new Diagnosis(0, null);// new diagnoses called as Diagnoses datatype
public ArrayList<Medication> newMedication = new ArrayList<Medication>();
//private Medication newMedication = new Medication(0, null);// newMedication called as medication datatype
ArrayList<String> symptom = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> symptomCompare = new ArrayList<String>();
private double weight;
private double height;
int k = 0;


public Patient(String firstName,String lastName,String address,String city, String state,String zip,String ssn,char gender,double weight,double height,String symptoms){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
    this.address = address;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.symptoms = symptoms;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.patientID = ssn.replace("-", ""); // removes dashes from ssn and sets the value to patientID
    this.patientID = this.patientID.replace(" ", ""); //removes spaces from patientID
    this.patientID = this.patientID + this.firstName.substring(0, 1) + this.lastName.substring(0, 1);


}
```

and above is the shortened patient class. I've been sitting here for a few hours trying different things but it keeps telling me to change the getPatientList() method to static. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Doctor.getPatientList()` is the syntax for calling a static method, since `Doctor` is a class name.

If you want to call an instance method (and `getPatientList()` is currently an instance method), you should call it using an instance of a `Doctor`:

```
Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
ArrayList<Patient> pList = doctor.getPatientList();
```

Comment: I can't believe I just wasted so much time on something so simple. Dear god. why. I feel so dumb right now

Answer (score 1):

What ever variables/method you declare as `static` as known as class members. Strictly speaking, they belongs to the class instead of being an object's attribute.

When a variable is `static`, it exist even before the object is created. So what does that means?

- Static methods can access static variables/methods.
- Static methods cannot access non-static variables/methods. (because they don't exist)

If you want to let static methods access non-static variables/methods. One of the ways is to instantiate(create) the object which the method/variable you wanted to access belong to that object first.

The reason you need to instantiate first before you can access it is because you want to make them **exist** first. Class itself is only a **blueprint**, you need to create an object (**to make them exist**) before you can interact with it.

**Example:**

```
Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
ArrayList<Patient> list = doctor.patientList;  
//Only possible if patientList is not private
```

If patientList is private in Class Doctor, you need to use a getter:

```
Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
ArrayList<Patient> list = doctor.getPatientList();  
//getPateientList is a method in Doctor class
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the class object first then call its function. Like:

```
Doctor doc = new Doctor();
doc.getPatientList();
```

Else you will have to make the function static.

Answer (score 0):

Use `static` modifier with `public ArrayList<Patient> getPatientList()`:

public **static** ArrayList getPatientList()

You are invoking this method on class `Doctor`, and thus this method must be declared static.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Doctor` class, the `patientList`, `loadPatientData()` and `getPatientList()` members are all "instance" members of the class `Doctor`, which means you need an instance or an object of the type `Doctor`.

So, to call `getPatientList()`, you need to create a `Doctor` object as below:

```
Doctor doc = new Doctor();
doc.getPatientList();
```

`static` members are accessed using the name of the class where as instance members are accessed using the name of the object.